# Cómo enviar parámetros desde diferentes métodos a un tercero?

Tags: c#

Imaginad que tenemos 3 métodos:

```
private double metodoa()
{
    //mi código 1
}

private double metodob()
{
    //mi código 2
}

private double metodoc(double a, double b)
{
    //mi código 3
}
```

La idea es la siguiente. El método c tiene que recibir 2 parámetros:

- uno del método a
- uno del método b

Trato de hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

- desde el método a: metodoc(miparametro1);
- desde el método b: metodoc(miparametro2);

Al pasar el parámetro desde cualquiera de los métodos a o b al método c me sale este error: "no se ha dado ningún argumento que corresponda con el parámetro formal requerido".

```
    private int suma()
    {
        int num1= 1;
        int num2= 2;
        int num1MASnum2 = num1 + num2;

        return num1MASnum2;
    }

    private int resta()
    {
        int num1= 100;
        int num2= 80;
        int num1MENOSnum2 = num1 - num2;

        return num1MENOSnum2;
    }

    private int resultado(int a, int b)
    {
        resultado = a * b;

        return resultado;
    }
```

Este sería un ejemplo de código (evidentemente este código es absurdo!!!)

Pero la pregunta real es:
¿Cómo paso al método resultado (que espera 2 parámetros) 1 SÓLO parámetro desde el método suma y 1 SÓLO parámetro desde el método resta?

Comment: Al método C debes pasar 2 parámetros ya que eso es lo que defines en ese método. De igual forma seria bueno que pusieras el código que estas creando.

Comment: Puedes mostrar mas codigo para contextualizar ?

Comment: En el ejemplo que proporcionas en ningun momento desde `suma()` o `resta()` estas invocando a `resultado()`. Ademas la funcionalidad que representa cada operacion como que no tienen ningun relacion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que intentas no es posible, al menos no del modo que quieres llamar a `metodoc(double a, double b)`.

Al momento de intentar llamar a double `metodoc()` pasándole sólo un parámetro tendrás siempre un error, debido a que no existe ninguna función llamada `metodoc` y reciba sólo un parámetro.

Sin embargo, lo lindo de la programación, es que siempre hay varios caminos para resolver un problema..

Por ejemplo, ¿Por qué no hacer un cuarto método?

```
private double metodod()
{
    //Obtengo el valor de la primer función.
    double a = metodoa();
    //Obtengo el valor de la segunda..
    double b = metodob();
    //Ahora si tengo toda la información que requiero para llamar a la tercera!
    double resultadoFinal = metodoc(a,b)
}
```

Comment: Mil gracias Juan. No sabía de esta posibilidad... estoy recién iniciándome en el mundo de la programación en C#. De nuevo... ¡¡¡GRACIAS!!!